# Cannot load underlying module for ‘accessibilitiy’ error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5

I’m new learner. I use SwiftUI in Playground. I want to show an image (my image size: 858 by 754 and 648 KB), and getting an error

> cannot load underlying module for ‘accessibility’

and

> File’/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8EA050EA-AEC5-4027 -8D03-0051E1F793F3/Library/Caches/com.apple.Playgrounds/ModuleCache/387THR7HHJWNH/Accessibility-3HTLLG0N0HRB7.pcm’ is not a valid preconpiled module file

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

  struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      Image("Example")
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
  }
}
```

I know it’s easy, but I need some help. How to solve it?

Comment: Error is not related to the code you posted (The code you posted works). Try to create a new playground, with just this code and see if error is reproducible.